Fraction field constant sheaf is direct sum of coherent sheaves
Let $X$ be an irreducible closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathbb{C}(X)$ denote the fraction field of $X$, and let $\underline{\mathbb{C}}$ denote the constant sheaf on $X$. How does one exhibit $\underline{\mathbb{C}}$ as an (arbitrary) direct sum of coherent sheaves? This is claimed in Serre's GAGA paper.

By projective do you mean closed subvariety of $\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb C}$?

Yes I do! Thanks.

I think the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb C(X)$ can be exhausted by line bundles.

@red_trumpet And how do you do this?

Given a rational function $f \in \mathbb C(X)$, let $D$ be its divisor of zeroes, so $f$ is global section of the line bundle $\mathcal O(D)$. By definition, $\mathcal O(D)$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal K_X$, the sheaf of total quotients of $\mathcal O_X$. But since $X$ is irreducible, $\mathcal K_X$ is the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb C(X)$.
